# Is there a way to find executable path with an electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm building a electron app that calls the PHP binary on whichever platform it is installed. For this I am calling the standard node's `child_process.spawn` like this:

```js
require('child_process').spawn('php', ['/path/to/artisan']);
```

While serving the electron app in development, this worked fine. However, when I build the electron app for standalone distribution, I got error saying `php is not found`.

Next, I modified the command to utilize `which` and resolve the executable path and rebuild the app again:

```js
require('child_process').spawn('$(which php)', ['/path/to/artisan']);
```

This didn't work as well and I got an error like:

```bash
env: php: No such file or directory
```

I can only infer that `$(which php)` returned empty and the shell command resolved to only `/path/to/artisan`. Hence, the error.

The content of the file `/path/to/artisan` begins like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
```

Judging from the error output, this means the `php` executable wasn't found as well.

Next, I found this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/real-executable-path) that can be used to resolve full path of a given executable. I tried this example:

```js
// test.js
const realExecutablePath = require("real-executable-path");

realExecutablePath("php").then((binPath) => {
    console.log(binPath);
});
```

When I run this with `node test.js`, I was able to get the full executable path. I proceed to move this into the electron app, build it and got this error thrown by the package:

```bash
Error: not found: php
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there a specific way to do this within electron?